# Accepting an agent forward in a Paramiko Server

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Ok, so you implement [`paramiko.ServerInterface.check_channel_forward_agent_request`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/server.html#paramiko.server.ServerInterface.check_channel_forward_agent_request) to accept or deny agent forwarding initiated by the client.

But neither [the docs](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/) nor [the code](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/) nor [the OpenSSH code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/) give any indication what you do next.

- Does the agent consume the channel or is it sideband? is it even associated with a specific channel?
- Is there an in-process way to call to the agent?
- How do I set up local socket for other programs to use the forwarded agent?
- How do I connect the agent forward to another paramiko transport for chain forwarding?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer:

```
def check_channel_forward_agent_request(self, channel):
    self.agent = AgentServerProxy(channel.transport)
    self.agent.connect()
    return True
```

However, you must also call `AgentServerProxy.close()`, and it might be necessary to call `AgentServerProxy.connect()` after the `return True` and the response has been returned to the client.